# Add "Open with Visual Studio Code" shortcut to right click menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, shortcut, right-click, regedit

**Step 1: Open Run and Access the Registry Editor**

[image: Opening Registry Editor]

**Step 2: Navigate to the Following Directory in the Registry Editor**

[image: Navigate to Directory]

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
```

**Step 3: Create a New Key**

[image: Create New Key in Shell]

**Setting Up the Name and Icon of the Shortcut:**

[image: Values]

- **(Default)**: "Shortcut Name" (e.g., "Open with Visual Studio Code")
- **Icon**: "Shortcut Icon" (Path to the icon, e.g., "Path to Code.exe in the example")

**Command:**

[image: Creating Command]

Create a new key in your directory and set the "(Default)" value to the command.

- **(Default)**: "Path to Visual Studio Code" "."

This is not a question but rather a guide on how to add the "Open with Visual Studio Code" option to the right-click menu.

Comment: "_This is not Question_" Then what is it? If you want to share knowledge, that's fine. Just do it on the right site, making sure that it's [on-topic](/help/on-topic), and separating the question and answer into question and answer posts (see [ask] and [answer]).

Answer (score 6):

For those who are new to the Registry Editor, here's an additional note for Step 3:

1. Double-click on the `(Default)` key to open a popup.
2. Enter your value there.

If you're entering "Open with Visual Studio Code," that's fine. However, if you're entering a path, remember to wrap your path in double quotes, as shown in the example above.

For instance, my icon value is:

```markdown
"C:\Users\PACKARD BELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

And my command value in the `command` key is:

```markdown
"C:\Users\PACKARD BELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .
```

Notice that with the `command` value here, we have the path wrapped in double quotes, as well as white space and a dot wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

- If Step 3 does not work for someone, they can still try using the placholder `"%1"`.

`"C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" "%1"`

- Adding the path to the icon to `VS Code` instead of `command`

`"C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" "%1"`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed through **Microsoft Dev Preview**, it didn't ask for any option and install it directly.

If you facing issue with where path is visible but correct directory not opening, put the **command** value as

> ```
> C:\Users\abhijit\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe "%V"
> ```
>
> where **%V** is **selected** directory

[image]